# "TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object." while creating JavaScript buttons using a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button, typeerror

I am trying to add buttons on a webpage and use the following procedure to do it.

```
var videoButtonDiv = document.createElement("div");
var startButton = videoButton("Start");
// add particular button to video button family
videoButtonDiv.appendChild(startButton);

function videoButton(buttonType){
    var bareButton = document.createElement("input");
    //Add attributes to the bare button
    bareButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    bareButton.setAttribute("class", "offcanvas_button");
    bareButton.setAttribute("id","video_button");
    //Tell the button what to display to the user
    if (buttonType=="Start"){
        bareButton.setAttribute("value", "Start");    
        bareButton.onclick = function(event){
            bareButton.innerHTML = "Stop";
            };
    }
    else if(buttonType=="Play"){
        bareButton.setAttribute("value", "Play");
        bareButton.onclick = function(event){
            bareButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
            };
    }
    return videoButton;
};
```

With the above snippet, I am trying to append a button that I create as part of a function as the child of a div element that holds a button family.

The error I get is with respect to `videoButtonDiv.appendChild(startButton);` with the following error `TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.` I do not understand what is causing this error.

Comment: `return videoButton` should be `return bareButton`

Comment: thank you for the pointer. made the change

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: But now the code won't result in the `TypeError`

Comment: Error present even after change.

Comment: This code won't throw a `TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object` - https://jsfiddle.net/z86b8nkj/

Comment: You are right, the console error I was looking at was from an older session. Thanks a lot.